# Почему не работает lxml.html.cssselect?

Tags: html, python, lxml, cssselect

Почему cssselect невыполняет поиск элементов?

```
import requests
from lxml.html import parse
from io import StringIO    
def getElement(url):
        r = requests.get(url)
        root = parse(StringIO(r.text)).getroot()
        links = root.cssselect('a')
        print(links)
```

Ошибка в логе:

> ```
> 'cssselect does not seem to be installed. ' ImportError: cssselect does not seem 
>          to be installed. See http://packages.python.org/cssselect/
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import html
def getElement(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    root = html.parse(StringIO(r.text)).getroot()
    links = root.cssselect('a')
    for link in links:
        print(link)
```

помогло с библиотеками, поднялся в html